# Collect items to Guava Multimap

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, guava

I'm trying to collect item to a final Guava `Multimap`.
I've noticed that `Flowable` has a `.toMultimap` but I can't figure out how to use it to return what I need.

Here is a snippet

```
Single<Map<String, Collection<String>>> map = getActiveUsers().toFlowable() //
        .flatMapIterable(users -> users) //
        .map(User::getFullName) //
        .distinct() //
        .toMultimap(FullName::first, FullName::second);
```

How can I change this code to return a Guava `Multimap<String,String>` instead of `Map<String,Collection<String>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collect`:

```
source.collect(
    HashMultimap::create, 
    (mmap, item) -> mmap.put(item.first, item.second)
)
```